# ZK binding string value to datebox

Tags: binding, zk

I have created a **Listbox** in which one column can contain different components like **Combobox**, **Datebox**, **Decimal box** etc. In One column I have to display **Datebox** or **Decimalbox**   on some condition so i bind **Datebox** and **Decimalbox** inside this column with **String** value. I am getting exception when I bind string value to **datebox** and try to enter the date using popup calender.

```
    <datebox value="@bind(data.prodValue)" width="250px"></datebox>

private String prodValue;
```

**prodValue** is of **String** type.When I enter the date in **Datebox**, I am getting exception.
Can anybody tell me how to use **Datebox** with string binding value?

Comment: Is their any specific reason you are binding Date with String you can bind it with java.sql.Timestamp class

Comment: but I have to use single variable to bind all components like datebox, decimabox etc

Comment: Can you provide a demo code in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

you can create customize datebox where  datatype String and Timestamp condition wize .
just set flag `type="String/Timestamp"`

find this class [here](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Datebox.html#setFormat%28java.lang.String%29) just extend in new customize class override setValue method and modify getValue method

Comment: I am not able to catch your logic.Can you elaborate it with some code?

Answer (score 0):

1. datebox use java.util.Date
2. if you bind @bind(data.prodValue) will be invoked getProdValue() method

Comment: if you want to work with string instead of Date, you can use converter @converter('path.ClassName') or @converter(yourVm.yourConverter). view model must contain "public Converter getYourConverter()" method

Comment: It means we can not use String datatype with datebox

Comment: it means converter need for converting date <-> string. view model will have string, datebox will have date. it will seems like we "use String datatype with datebox"